# How to set timezone in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a simple gnuplot command file:

```
 ....
set xdata time
set timefmt "%s"
set format x "%H:%M"
....
```

where x - timestamp column.

Result - time in UTC format. Can I change local timezome for x axis ?

Comment: can you provide some sample data?

Comment: I've made some attempts at this and am afraid that I failed ... but I'm not big on timezone `strptime` magic, so maybe someone else will manage.

Comment: I see this question is quite old and it seems the answer has not changed since. I find awful to have to modify the data to get a proper date rendering. Any change in newer versions ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just came across this in the docs today:

> The conversion to and from seconds assumes Universal Time (which is the same
>    as Greenwich Standard Time).  There is no provision for changing the time
>    zone or for daylight savings.  If all your data refer to the same time zone
>    (and are all either daylight or standard) you don't need to worry about these
>    things.  But if the absolute time is crucial for your application, you'll
>    need to convert to UT yourself.

From `help time/date`

Answer (score 7):

I just ran across this today. You don't need to change the format, just change the data. If data.txt contains timestamps in UTC, and you want to display them in PDT (-7 hours off from UTC), simply use:

```
plot 'data.txt' using ($1+(-7*3600)):2
```

This subtracts 7 hours (in seconds) from each x value.

Comment: You can get the offset using date command:  date +%s -d '1 Jan 1970'

Comment: A refinement to anthonie’s comment: `date +%z` yields the current numeric time zone and `date +%z --date=@1520000000` yields the numeric time zone for the epoch time 1520000000.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, and I don't have enough reputation points to comment, but to add to anthony and hermannk's answer, this is how I implemented it with their information:

- in `command.gnuplot`, assuming that the first field contains the date/time and the second field contains the value for the Y axis:

`plot "inputfile" using ($1 - offset):2`

- from the (bash) command line, when invoking gnuplot:

`gnuplot -e "offset=$(date +%s -d '1 Jan 1970')" command.gnuplot`

The offset generally will work OK because gnuplot internally interprets date/time as seconds from epoch. I don't know if the form `"offset=$(date ...)"` is a bash specific thing, but you could always use `` "offset=`date ...`" `` instead.

EDIT --
I found this not to work very well when dealing with DST/Summer Time changes. I changed the offset calc to this, and now it works better:

- in `command.gnuplot`, assuming that the first field contains the date/time and the second field contains the value for the Y axis:

`plot "inputfile" using ($1 + offset):2`

- from the (bash) command line, when invoking gnuplot:

`gnuplot -e "offset=$(echo "$(date +%z) * 36" | bc)" command.gnuplot`

How does this work?
`date +%z` provides the timezone offset in the form `-0400` or similar, which means `Local_Time = UTC - 4 hours`. If we consider this a number (-400), then the offset, in seconds, is -400 / 100 * 3600 = -400 * 36.
Note that this won't work with timezones that have 30 minutes increments (India?), but I'm sure with some creating math, you can cover that as well.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet posted here did not work for me, but this seems to do the trick:

```
TZ=Europe/Amsterdam tzoff=$(printf "%(%z)T")
tzoff=${tzoff:0:1}$(( ( 10#${tzoff:1:2} * 3600 + 10#${tzoff:3:2}* 60 ) ))
echo $tzoff
```

Answer (score 0):

Moin,

I formely had similar problems as the thread-opener and came across a syntax like

```
plot "wave/timeseries.csv" using ($1+(2*3600)):2 title "swh" with l lw 2
```

to display forcast of significant-wave-height forecast (bsh.de).
That was fine until a few days ago when I wanted to plot from a bash script to automatically upload gnuplot diagrams for sharing with friends.

```
#!/bin bash
tz=`date +%j`
tz=`echo "0$tz / 100 * 3600" | bc`
xyz...
gnuplot --persist <<EOF
abc...
plot "wave/timeseries.csv" using ($1+$tz):2 title "swh" with l lw 2
EOF
```

The problem was, that bash replaces the $1 (data field) by the not existing (NULL) cli argument. Escaping, brackets,... nothing did help.

My workaround is now to from within the script I do write the plot command with escaping to tmp-file like

```
echo "plot \"wave/timeseries.csv\" using (\$1+$tz):2 title \"swh\" with l lw 2" > plotcmd.tmp
```

and "load plotcmd.tmp" it from within the gnuplot section.
This way it works

All the best from the baltic sea
Chris