# Gnuplot plots incorrect time for time series plot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, time-series

I'm printing a time series that has the following format

```
> 1400536853 0.011955 
> 1400537188 0.013695 
> 1400537530 0.010797  
> ....
> 1400621709 0.010688 
> 1400622023 0.007209 
> 1400622338 0.006685 
> 1400622653 0.005539
```

The first column is a timestamp in unix epoch format and the second is a variable to plot.
Notice that the timestamp pf the first line corresponds to "Tue May 20 00:00:53 CEST 2014" and the last line to "Tue May 20 23:50:53 CEST 2014". I veridied this with the following command:

```
date -d @<timestamp>
```

I'm using the following script to plot the time series

```
set xdata time
set timefmt '%s'
set format x '%H'
plot 'series.txt' using 1:2 with lines notitle
```

But I'm getting a plot with hours in the range 22, 00, 02. ...22 as shown in the next figure:

[image: time series plot]

I will appreciate any suggestion on how to fix this. May this has to do with not setting properly the timezone? Many thanks in advance

Comment: I just came across [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14514652/476065) in another stackoverflow's question. Apparently, it's a limitation of gnuplot, which always assumes Universal Time when converting timestamps in seconds from epoch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gnuplot cannot change the time zone and uses UTC for all time data. This is where your 2h shift comes from:

```
$ date -u -d @1400536853
Mo 19. Mai 22:00:53 UTC 2014
```

In your specific case, you can just add the two hours in the `using` statement:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt '%s'
set format x '%H'
plot 'series.txt' using ($1 + 2*60*60):2 with lines notitle
```

Beware, that this explicitely assumes, that you run the script only on computers in the same time zone. I think there is no generic way to convert between time zones within gnuplot, since it doesn't support them.

Answer (score 4):

Following [Christoph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23804347/476065), I figure out how to calculate the offset in a generic way in the script that call gnuplot:

```
   LOCAL=$(date)
   UTC=$(date -u -d "$LOCAL" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")  #remove timezone reference
   UTCSECONDS=$(date -d "$UTC" +%s)
   LOCALSECONDS=(date -d "$LOCAL" +%s)        
   TIMEZONEGAP=$(($LOCALSECONDS-$UTCSECONDS))
```

Then in gnuplot I can use this gap as proposed

Comment: There is a typo: LOCALSECONDS=$(date -d "$LOCAL" +%s)
I am being refused the correction because it is too short an edit!