# Gnuplot prints a strange year, 30 years later

Tags: date, time, gnuplot

I have the next problem with gnuplot, when I print the time gnuplot
prints de time+30years.

This is a part of my data:

```
1411336800,1390,0,0,0,10,1411,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,1411
1411340400,1506,0,0,0,10,969,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,969
1411344000,1115,0,0,0,10,1108,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,1108
1411347600,719,0,0,0,10,712,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,712
```

A part of the script is:

```
set timefmt "%s"
stats "<tail -1 uur.txt " using 1:2 nooutput
tijd = strftime("%d %B %Y %H:%M", STATS_max_x)
print tijd
```

And then gnuplot prints: 21 September 2044 01:00.  44 ?

Has some one a clue?

I tried several formats but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until version 4.6, internally gnuplot uses the 1. January 2000 as reference for its date and time functions (in version 5.0 the standard Unix timestamp is used).

You shouldn't have any problems with `set timefmt "%s"` if you plot the data. But when using `strftime` it makes a difference. Since you're using `tail` anyway, you can simply use

```
tijd = system('date -d @$(tail -1 uur.txt | cut -d, -f1) +"%d %B %Y %H:%M"')
print tijd
```

Comment: Almost unbelievable that you known such details. It works perfect, Thanks a very, very and again very lot!

Comment: Another little problem, the Years are now good but there is a different with the hours. The time must be 20:00 but gnuplot prints 22:00. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, see [Gnuplot plots incorrect time for time series plot](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803630/2604213).

Comment: I read your link. Do you know how to implement this in your first solution? I have no idea...

Comment: Then probably your data was saved as UTC and `date` uses your local time zone. Try using `date -u -d ...`.

Comment: Absolutely perfect!! Thanks again.